# StringBuilder implements Comparable but does not override equals

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I don't understand this [line from javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (under the subheading "API note"):

> StringBuilder implements Comparable but does not override equals. Thus, the natural ordering of StringBuilder is inconsistent with equals.

I am a beginner in Java so could you explain this in a simple way?

Comment: I'm not sure why they decided to do this, but it mainly means that you shouldn't use a StringBuilder as a key for any List (you shouldn't be using StringBuilder for that purpose anyway). Or try to sort it unless you are only using Comparable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That means `StringBuilder.compareTo()` and `StringBuilder.equals()` don't always agree.

```java
var sb1 = new StringBuilder("foo");
var sb2 = new StringBuilder("foo");
assert sb1.compareTo(sb2) == 0;      // as you would expect.
assert sb1.equals(sb2) == true;      // surprise - it fails
```

Now it gets a bit more confusing:

```java
var map = new HashMap<StringBuilder, String>();
map.put(sb1, "lorem ipsum");
assert map.size() == 1;
map.put(sb2, "dolor sit amet");
assert map.size() == 1;            // fails - it's 2

var set = new TreeSet<StringBuilder>();
set.add(sb1);
assert set.size() == 1;
set.add(sb2);
assert set.size() == 2;           // you'd think this should be 2 but it fails!
```

That's because HashMap works with `equals()` whereas `SortedSet` with `compareTo()`.

---

**NOTE 1: on `equals()`**

`StringBuilder` extends `Object`, which means it inherits `Object.equals()`; but it does not override `equals()`, which means `StringBuilder.equals()` is actually `Object.equals()`.

`Object.equals()` in turn is basically `==`, ie it returns true if and only if the two objects are the same memory address.

[Object.equals() java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

---

**NOTE 2: why?**

Only starting from JDK11, `StringBuilder` implements `Comparable`. Any accompanying change in `equals()` could have caused some older client code to break; so, I'd think, following the Java tradition of keeping things backward compatible they dropped the idea.

Comment: Sir, I am a beginner I don't know about the whole sorted set and hashMap concepts.Sir, but StringBuilder does not have equals then how a HashMap uses equals, does it coverts StringBuilder to String sir? 
sorry for my

Comment: Thank you, sir. Now I got clear understanding sir.

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to mark the answer.